# Android GCM, want to push custom message

Tags: php, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

How to push messages into Google Cloud Messaging?

I've viewed this: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/>Android Hive Info

I've tweaked the script a little bit to send messages to everyone in one go.

I just want to push a message from three different fields in a form. How do I go about it?

Here's the code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["message"])) {
include_once 'db_functions.php';
$db = new DB_Functions();
$users = $db->getAllUsers();
$regIds = array();
if ($users != false){
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($users)) {
        $regIds[] = $row["gcm_regid"];
    }
}

include_once './GCM.php';

$gcm = new GCM();

$registatoin_ids = $regIds;
$message = "array("price" => $_GET["message"]);"

$result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);

echo $result;
```

}
?>

Comment: Looks like your `$message` declaration might be broke.  How about `$message = array("price" => $_GET["message"]);`

Comment: It is actually working fine right now. But all I want to do is insert a custom message. I want to send a title, body and footer in the same message.